# bus error on armv7l

Tags: robotic-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to run the a modified version of asctec_autopilot on a gumstix overo tide (armv7l). Running the nodes is not a problem. But when I try do launch nodelets I get bus errors (http://pastebin.com/MXe6bAUB).

Is this somehow related to https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2883 and can I solve this by applying that patch? Or is there a fault on my side?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12135/bus-error-on-armv7l/) by [olebowle](https://answers.ros.org/users/1459/olebowle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a thread that might be related http://code.ros.org/lurker/thread/20121128.193914.99c8dd91.en.html#i20121128.193914.99c8dd91

That ticket also does look relevant.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0